# Least Upper Bound Theorem and Completeness

Tags: real-analysis

Can someone please explain how exactly the Least Upper Bound theorem proves completeness of a set, intuitively?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's look at the real number. The Least Upper Bound Property of the reals states that every non-empty subset of $\mathbb{R}$ with an upper bound has a least upper bound.

A least upper bound(l.u.b) of a set $S$ is the smallest number that is larger than all the numbers in the set. In other word, if you choose any number just slightly smaller than it, there will be an infinitely many numbers in the set that is larger than the chosen number. If you take any open interval that contains the l.u.b, that interval also contains an infinite number of elements in $S$.

Imagine taking a smaller and smaller interval that contains the l.u.b. From each intervals choose an elements from the set $S$ that is also inside the interval. Then you end up with an infinite sequence of elements in $S$ that gets closer and closer to the l.u.b. This sequence of element of $S$ will have to converge to the l.u.b so if we take it out, the sequence will converge to something out of $\mathbb{R}$, contrasting its completeness. This is why the existence of the l.u.b of every set is essential to completeness.

Hope this helps.